# how asp.net application defaultly loading default.aspx

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an existing asp.net application. When I ran the code in my local machine, it is directly opening default.aspx. It is not configured in web.config. How does the application know to open default.aspx?

Comment: The web server , in your case i assume IIS will always pick default.aspx or index.aspx as start page , thats what happening in your application , you can also set some other page as default page in visual studio to run on local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

The web server, in our case IIS Express, has a default document configuration. If you don't define a page in the URL, it'll try to find a default file (`Default.htm`, `Default.asp`, `Default.aspx`, etc.).

See more details [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument).

## Option 2

In Visual Studio you can configure a Start page. If you run (debug) the solution VS will open the page you configured. Right click the file and select `Set As Start Page`.

You can configure the start page in the project's properties dialog too:

[image: Project Properties Web tab]

Comment: Thanks David. In my case, default.aspx was set as Start page(from right click option of default.aspx file).

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with the answer then feel free to mark it as an answer and you could upvote it as well :)

Comment: am new here. Even though I upvoted, it is not getting displayed der :-)